# I have a planet eating my donut

Tags: particles

When I have gotten to the sprinkles part, everything went as it should.  I am back to that point and instead of the thin white cookie hanging off the side of the donut, mine looks like a planet eating my donut.  I have no idea what I changed but it started out looking like shaving cream with a little icing top stuck into it.  Does anyone know, just by looking at this, what setting I have amiss or what I neglected to do?  The first jpg is the shaving cream, the second is the planet, the third is the tutorial.
[image: ShavingCreamDonut]

[image: PlanetEatingDonut]
[image: AndrewPriceVid]

Comment: Your particle system is set to emitter, so it is emitting particles over time.  At frame 90 the particles have completely covered your object.  If you set your timeline back to frame 1 it should look like it did before.

Comment: +1 for the clickbait title

Answer (score 1):

Your particle system is set to **emitter**, set it to **hair**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  If I hit the hair button, it tuns into those wire looking strands all over the donut.  I have my playback at 1 and the huge white ball still shows up when I place it, not the thin white wafer as in the vid.  This is my favorite part of this tutorial but this time it looks very different.  I am a wee bit obsessive compulsive and if my project is not perfect like Andrew's, I freak out.  Hey, good job on the cup and saucer!

Comment: Hi, if the hair strands appear then it means you are doing everything right. There are two types of particle system , emitter and hair, emitter is used for explosion and stuff and hair is used for spreading objects on a mesh. Later in the donut tutorial you will see how to change those strands into sprinkles. You should not worry about the sphere and wafer part coz u r not going to use that option(emitter) at all in that video. Andrew Price have done a great job explaining everything, if you get stuck somewhere don't worry just watch a min or two ahead or read the comments section.

Comment: Also, don't worry about getting everything perfect. At first, I too tried getting everything just right but with experience, I realized that it didn't matter if something was a little different than the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you.  I try to keep that in mind but still panic.  I was just a tiny bit adventurous and instead of fighting with the icing to touch the donut, I just made the donut bigger.  Your explanation of the hair put that into perspective for me.

Comment: You're welcome.